# Show that a group homomorphism $f$ is the identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $f$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_7\times\mathbb Z_7$ to itself satisfying $f^5 = \operatorname{id}$ (where $f^5=f\circ f\circ f\circ f\circ f$). Show that $f$ is the identity.

Comment: Group homomorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}_7,+)$ or field homomorphism?

Comment: I think it's the group homomorphism of $(\mathbb Z_7\times\mathbb Z_7,+)$

Comment: So how can you describe all group homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Comment: We only need to determine $f((1,0))$ and $f((0,1))$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

- In a group $G$ (what group? Its order divides $42\cdot 48$) if $a\in G$ then $a^{|G|}=\mathrm{id}$.
- If $a^k=\mathrm{id}$ and $a^n=\mathrm{id}$ then $a^{\gcd(k,n)}=\mathrm{id}$.

Can you apply the above to your problem? What if $f^3=\mathrm{id}$ or $f^{11}=\mathrm{id}$?

Comment: Is the group $G$ of all group homomorphisms?  why dose its order divide $42\cdot 48$?

Comment: Since the fifth power of the homomorphism is identity, it’s an automorphism, and thus is contained in the automorphism group of the dimension-two vector space in question. This automorphism group is $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb F_7)$. A simple counting argument shows that this group has order $(7^2-1)(7^2-7)$. (I must say that I find this answer very slick and very satisfying!)

Answer (score 8):

One can think of $f$ as a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb Z_7$. Since $f^5$ is identity one gets $A^5=I_2$. This shows that the minimal polynomial of $A$, denoted by $m_A$, divides $X^5-1$. But $$X^5-1=(X-1)(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)$$ and $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_7$ (why?). Thus we have $m_A=X-1$ and therefore $A=I_2$, that is, $f$ is the identity.

Comment: Why can you think of $f$ as a $2\times 2$ matrix with entries in $\Bbb Z_7$?

Comment: I think $f((1,0))$ and $f((0,1))$ are the four elements in the $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: A group homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z_7\times\mathbb Z_7\to \mathbb Z_7\times\mathbb Z_7$ is also an $\mathbb Z_7$-vector space homomorphism.